# Split by commas that are not within parentheses?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I want to split by commas that are not within parentheses in Excel VBA.

I need VBA script for split string

Ex:

```
myString = "ab, cd(c1,c2,d1), ef, gh ,ij(i1,i2,j1,j2)"
```

E need output as below :

```
[ 
  ab,
  cd(c1,c2,d1),
  ef,
  gh,
  ij(i1,i2,j1,j2) 
]
```

Comment: @braX, i need answer in VBA

Comment: And we need to see the code you have tried so far because this is no free code writing service. Please read [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parentheses are always singly-nested, splitting on the following regex should work:

```
,(?![^(]*\))
```

This uses a negative lookahead which asserts that we don't split on a comma after which follows a `)` *without* first encountering an `(`, which means another group is being opened.

I don't know if VBA would support lookaheads in its regex though.  Check the demo below to see the pattern working.

### Demo